# Set variable in jinja but got TemplateSyntaxError

Tags: python, html, templates, jinja2, variable-assignment

I was trying to assign value to my variables like this

```
{% for song in songs %}
  {% set song.ID = userID   %}
{% endfor%}
```

But I got this

```
TemplateSyntaxError: expected token '=', got '.'
```

I wonder how I can get this right.Thank you!

Comment: You can not assign to (sub) attributes in Jinja.